# What's the regex to capture values which init string until end word?

Tags: java, regex

My Entries:

```
String e1 = "MyString=1234 MyString=5678";
String e2 = "MyString=1234\nMyString=5678";
```

What i'm doing:

```
String pattern = "MyString=(.*)";
Pattern patternObj = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher matcher = patternObj.matcher(e1);  //e1 or e2
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("G1: " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("G2: " + matcher.group(2));
}
```

What i want in output:

```
G1: 1234
G2: 5678
```

Comment: Replace `.` with `\w` (`"\\w"`). However, it seems you could just split these strings with whitespace and then with `=`.

Comment: This works fine Wiktor. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest "quick fix" is to replace `.` (any char but a newline) with `\w` (a letter, digit or an underscore):

```
String pattern = "MyString=(\\w*)"; // <---- HERE
Pattern patternObj = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher matcher = patternObj.matcher(e1); 
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("G1: " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("G2: " + matcher.group(2));
}
```

Now, `MyString=(\\w*)` matches a `MyString=` substring and matches and captures any 0 or more letters, digits or underscores after it *not* matching any whitespace, punctuation, and other non-word chars.

**NOTE**: If you need to match any chars but whitespace, you may use `\S` instead of `\w`.

Answer (score 2):

There's only one group that will be matched multiple times. You have to keep matching and printing group 1:

```
int i = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("G" + (++i) + ": " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

Also, you need to update your pattern so it doesn't match the next `MyString`. You can use `\d+` or `\w+` or `[^\s]+`, depending on the type of values you're matching.

Answer (score 1):

If it will always be numbers, you could use this as your regex:

```
String pattern = "MyString=([0-9]*)";
```

If it will contain letters as well as numbers, Wiktor Stribizew's comment is very helpful in the original post. He said to use \w which matches on word characters.